# applying dynamic solution to Pyqt5 connection

Tags: python, user-interface, dynamic, pyqt5

Here is one simple code from Zetcode.com, that I am studying:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
ZetCode PyQt5 tutorial 

In this example, we create a skeleton
of a calculator using a QGridLayout.

author: Jan Bodnar
website: zetcode.com 
last edited: January 2015
"""

import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QGridLayout, 
    QPushButton, QApplication)


class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):

        grid = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(grid)

        names = ['Cls', 'Bck', '', 'Close',
                 '7', '8', '9', '/',
                '4', '5', '6', '*',
                 '1', '2', '3', '-',
                '0', '.', '=', '+']

        positions = [(i,j) for i in range(5) for j in range(4)]

        for position, name in zip(positions, names):

            if name == '':
                continue
            button = QPushButton(name)
            grid.addWidget(button, *position)

        self.move(300, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Calculator')
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Now, I am trying to apply the `button.setDisable` option for every button which is clicked.

One way is to create a new list and append each button to the created list. From this list, we could do following:

```
button_list[0].clicked.connect(self.on_click):
button_list[1].clicked.connect(self.on_click1):
```

And for each new method, we would then need to define:

```
def on.click(self):
    button_list[0].setEnabled(False)
```

This is a solution that works. But is there any more dynamic way to solve this issue?

Would appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `lambda` or `functools.partial`, you can do just that:

```
def on.click(self, numb):
    button_list[numb].setEnabled(False)
```

Invoke with `lambda`:

```
button_list[1].clicked.connect(lambda: self.on_click(1))
```

Or with `partial`:

```
button_list[1].clicked.connect(partial(self.on_click, 1))
```

Comment: Thank you Flippy. I find partial function very useful as well for the further developement.